# GWT RequestFactory: implementing InstanceRequest methods in separate services

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I am using a class separate from my DAO to handle access requests, but I don't know how to implement InstanceRequest methods:

```
public class Service
{
    public static DAO findDAO(Long id);
}

@Service(Service.class)
public interface DAORequestContext extends RequestContext
{
    Request<ProxyForDAO> findDAO(Long id);
    InstanceRequest<ProxyForDAO, Long> persist();
}
```

I define `public Long persist()` in my `DAO` implementation, because the [gwt docs say](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html), "On the server, instance methods must be implemented as non-static methods in the entity type," but request factory can't seem to find it:

`SEVERE: Could not find any methods named persist in com.activegrade.server.data.Service
Feb 23, 2011 10:03:02 PM com.google.gwt.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator die`

How do I implement an instance method in `Service`?  I don't know how to transform the `InstanceRequest`.  Do I need to connect the `DAO` class to the `Service` some way, so that the code generator knows to look in `Service` for most methods but to skip over to the `DAO` for `InstanceRequest` calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASAIK it's not possible because the `InstanceRequest` methods are bound to the class specified in the `@Service` annotation. With `Request` methods it is possible to have a method for multiple data classes one service class, using locators. But from what I understand of request factory this is not possible with the `InstanceRequest` methods. See also this project, which uses Locators, with methods in one place: http://code.google.com/p/listwidget/

Edit: I've rewritten the answer based after the update/and comment below.

Comment: I rewrote the example - I *am* using the Proxy in the RequestContext declaration, but miswrote it in my original question. I have RequestFactory working correctly for two other types of DAO/Proxy;this is the first time I've used a service outside the DAO class itself.  Re. the `persist()` method: How can I define the persist() method in the `Service` class?  I don't know how to transform an `InstanceRequest` method outside of `DAO`.  The docs say, "On the server, instance methods must be implemented as non-static methods in the entity type," but how can I connect `DAO` and `Service`?